# React Router: Check that JWT is valid before rendering a Private Route

Tags: authentication, react-router, jwt

I'm looking to implement a real world authentication for a `React Router` app. Every tutorial I've seen uses `fakeAuth` to simulate authentication, but doesn't actually implement real world authentication. I'm trying to actually implement authentication. Is this possible?

Right now I'm sending a `jwt` to the back end to check whether it is valid before returning the `Component` I want to render -- `Redirect` to `Login` if `jwt` authentication fails, or `render` `Dashboard` if it's a valid `jwt`. The problem is the `ProtectedRoute` is `return`ing the `redirect` to `/login` before the back end is `return`ing whether the `jwt` is valid or not.

**How can I get real world authentication in my `React-Router` app? Is this even possible?**

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {

  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {}, [auth])

  useEffect(() => {
    // send jwt to API to see if it's valid
    let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (token) {
      fetch("/protected", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ token })
      })
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json()
      })
      .then((json) => {
        if (json.success) {
          setAuth(true);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setAuth(false);
        localStorage.removeItem("token");
      });
    }

  }, [])

  return (<Route {...rest}
    render={(props) => {
      return auth ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
    }} />)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say you need a state between authenticated/not valid jwt. I would use another state field, isTokenValidated (or isLoading):

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {

  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false);
  const [isTokenValidated, setIsTokenValidated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // send jwt to API to see if it's valid
    let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (token) {
      fetch("/protected", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ token })
      })
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json()
      })
      .then((json) => {
        if (json.success) {
          setAuth(true);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setAuth(false);
        localStorage.removeItem("token");
      })
      .then(() => setIsTokenValidated(true));
    } else {
       setIsTokenValidated(true); // in case there is no token
    }

  }, [])

 if (!isTokenValidated) return <div />; // or some kind of loading animation

  return (<Route {...rest}
    render={(props) => {
      return auth ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
    }} />)
  }
}
```

Comment: For something that I imagine is a pretty common issue, I had not been able to find a solution to this anywhere else on SO, Youtube, or anywhere on the Internet, and you've done it. Many, many, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative way, your backend server.js file can check if jwt is valid or not and send a status code accordingly. Then your frontend react component can check this status code and render (or not render) page accordingly.

For component:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";
const Private = () => {

  const [statusAuth, setStatusAuth] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/privateroute")
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.status === 200) {
        setStatusAuth(true)
      } else {
        setStatusAuth(false)
      }
    });
  }, []);
  
  return(
    {statusAuth && <div>rendered page</div>}
    {!statusAuth && <div>You need to login. <Link to="/login"><span>Click for login page</span></Link></div>}
  )
}
```

For server.js file:

```
app.get("/privateroute", function(req, res){
  const token = req.cookies.jwt;
  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, "signature-of-your-jwt-token", () => {
      res.status(200).end();
    })
  } else {
    res.status(404)
    res.send("Tokens didnt match");
  }
});
```